# How do I make a form that changes color with input text in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, forms

I'm new to Ruby, and I want to develop a program that asks, "What's your favorite color?." And once you type in your favorite color, the submit button changes to the color, and the next screen's background will be that color you typed in.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Ruby itself is a programming language. This question implies that you're developing web applications (you said "submit button" and used the `forms` tag). You might want to specify a framework (e.g., Ruby on Rails, Sinatra) that you are using.

Comment: @sealocal is spot-on. Additionally, you should look into the difference between server-side and client-side code. The user interface you are describing will likely utilize a combination of server-side (Ruby for example) and client-side (JavaScript) code. The code that handles the form will likely be written in Ruby, whereas the code handling the dynamic elements of the page (submit button changing color, background changing color) should be written in JavaScript.

Comment: You can do it by Jquery/Javascript onClick function by applying class name and css to your form.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `CSS` and `javascript`. You could have a class `background-color-blue` with `background-color: blue` for example on your `body` or custom element.

Then, when submit is clicked, you simply change the class to `background-color-red`.

`document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "background-color-red";`

I would do some research using google/stackoverflow on how to change an elements css class depending on which web framework and programming languages you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a colorize gem, where you can change the color of text.

First, install the gem

```
gem install 'colorize'
```

Then, require the gem

```
require 'colorize'
```

You can now easily change the color of text.

```
string.colorize(:blue)               => Changes your text color to blue
```

In your case, this can be implemented as follows

```
puts "What's your favorite color?"
color = gets.chomp
puts color.colorize(color.to_sym)
```

Hope this helps.